# Проверка ввода и вывода программы через subprocess.run()

Tags: python, python-3.5, subprocess

Програмирую на Python 3.5(новичок)
Начал писать автотест для проверки кода,столкнулся с модулем 'subprocess.run()'
У меня существует файл plus_ten.py с содержимом внутри:

```
x = input()
sum = x + x
print(sum)
```

Как мне реализовать проверку его вывода с помощью 'subprocess'?.Смог написать лишь этот кусочек:

```
import subprocess
file_path = r'plus_ten.py'
    with open(file_path, 'r') as test_file:
    stdin = test_file.read().strip()
    p = subprocess.run(stdin, ???)
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `subprocess.check_output` и вывести результат

Comment: @gil9red По конкретней можете ответить, каким образом?

Comment: изучите [документацию subprocess](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-subprocess.html)